# MathJax in suggested edits

Tags: bug, mathjax, review-system

Pages like
https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/1435
display suggested edits for review.  The original and edited versions are displayed in parallel columns with the differences highlighted.  The highlighting seems to break the MathJax formatting.  This is especially a problem when the whole point of the edit is to fix formatting issues.

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue. I think there were several requests for it to be somehow circumvented (e.g. detect MathJax code and add the color tags outside it) on meta.MSE.

Comment: For the time being: a work-around is to click on the "improve" button. If you find that the Math does appear correctly in the preview, you can hit "cancel" to get out of the improvement screen and then accept the proposed edit.

Comment: See also: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4393/parsing-of-revisions-involving-insertion-of-dollar-signs

Comment: Relevant meta.MSE question: [Reviewing Suggested Edits](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/reviewing-suggested-edits).