# Rendering and inconsistency issues when reviewing edits

Tags: bug, review-system

I was reviewing an edit, and had two issues with it:

1. You can view the markdown and the rendered output.  I assume the rendered output would render the MathJax as well, but it didn't.
2. I tried to improve the edit, but the edit in the Improve form was different from the original edit I saw on the comparison page when I decided the edit needed improvement.

**Rendered output on comparison page not rendering MathJax**
[image: Rendered output on comparison page not rendering MathJax]

**Improve form, with edit contents different from what was on comparison page**
[image: Improve form, with edit contents different from what was on comparison page]

Answer (score 3):

re 1. That the preview in the review-system does not work is annoying but known, see [MathJax in suggested edits](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/73/mathjax-in-suggested-edits)  A workaround is to select 'improve' where it does work, and then to 'cancel' the improvement to then 'approve' (assuming of course one just wants to approve).

re 2. The question got edited/improved by another reviewer in parallel. The version you got for improving/editing, is the version that already contains their changes.