# Review suggestions MathJax

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, review-system, suggested-edits

Can we please turn on MathJax in "Rendered output" of "Suggested edits"? Or am I not qualified unless I can read raw LaTeX?

Comment: Earlier posts here and at meta.MSE about the same issue: [MathJax in suggested edits](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/73/55893), [Reviewing Suggested Edits](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2809/166535), [Why we can't see suggested edits rendered in latex before approving?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13360/166535).

Comment: I agree that the problem should be fixed. Could you have a switch for turning of the color coding so that MathJax would render things correctly?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks for the info (and workaround in the link). Closing as a duplicate.